# Cannot get gps coordinates from arduino to bind with kivy mapview

Tags: python, kivy

Image (1) is my lat and lon data from my gps shield. I then split them up into two datas : `lat_text` and `lon_text` in my python file. Im trying to put the variables in their respective mapview lat and lon. However when i run the code all i get is a blank map (image 2). I then tried to print the values from the arduino serial monitor to python by adding `print (self.lon_text)` and `print (self.lat_text)` and i realise that the values started to print out zeros first and then my actual gps lat and lon.(image 3)

[image: Arduino serial monitor]

[image: Blank map]

[image: lat and lon printed started with 0]

.py file

```
import threading    
import serial
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView, MapMarker
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

KV = """

WindowManager:
    NaviWindow:

<NaviWindow>:


"""



class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class NaviWindow(Screen):
    lat_text = NumericProperty()
    lon_text = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NaviWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        threading.Thread(target=self.tm).start()
        self.map = MapView(zoom=18, lat=self.lat_text, lon=self.lon_text, double_tap_zoom = True)
        self.marker_1 = MapMarker(lat=self.lat_text, lon=self.lon_text)
        self.map.add_marker(self.marker_1)
        self.add_widget(self.map)

    def tm(self):
        while (1):
            with serial.Serial('COM4', 9600) as ser:
                data = str(ser.readline().strip().decode('ascii'))
                ser.close()
                self.update_values(data.split("|"))
                print (self.lon_text)
                print (self.lat_text)

    @mainthread
    def update_values(self, data):
        self.lat_text = float(data[0])  # data[0] It's still a string
        self.lon_text = float(data[1])  # You need to specify that that part is a number

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Have you tried checking the contents of the string are what you expect?

Comment: Can you show what data.split("|") is doing?

Comment: i have edited my question showing what data split does @PabloGod